# CSS is no longer active on the WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

CSS is no longer active on the WordPress

Hello, I do not understand why the site does not display the style anymore.
I don't know where to attack the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQdRe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52N0b.png)

What I tried,

plugin for Delete unused css in WP using Asset CleanUp
link

It is possible to refactor (rework) the site code to remove unnecessary parts.
Link Doc
I can't do a refactoring

Load scripts and styles
it doesn't work
link

WP doc
wp_body_open

Comment: Is the `enqueue` present in the functions file, and does it have a unique name?

Comment: did you accidentally offload your main stylesheet?

Comment: Queuing is not in the function file

Comment: @StevenKuipers No on other browser the site load correctly on the picture I am on mozilla firefox   [link](https://lesecopepites.fr/) _italic_

Comment: On mozilla firefox here is what I have in the console, and I do not have these errors on chrome
[link_image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/921330217153331201/1068084224298598450/Capture_decran_704.png)

Comment: I tested to move the jQuery and jquery-ui-core
 To see the behavior.
On pc with Chrome, brave, firefox.
The style and returned, but with EDGE no, it is the same style error.

On mobile : The style is not at all back and it doesn't matter the browser.
Chrome, brave, safari, Firefox.

Comment: Here are the 2 states with the classic link [https://lesecopepites.fr/](https://lesecopepites.fr/) [Img](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/921330217153331201/1068130574339936396/Capture_decran_2023-01-26_122848.png)
it's 200^^

but with a link tracker [link-tracker](https://lesecopepites.fr/boutique/?utm_source=Insta&utm_medium=bio&utm_campaign=Linktree)
[Igm2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/921330217153331201/1068130574625165382/Capture_decran_2023-01-26_122910.png)

I have this style error because it doesn't find the Jquery.

Comment: Did you know if the link tracker can impact the style of the site?